# Adding 12 vectors together only to have all inputs and outputs undefined in simulation

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I am trying to add the amount of attendee's from 12 different sections (A-L) together to get an overall attendance. Each section's input is a 9-bit vector which all gets added to form a 14-bit vector. However when I try to implement a testbench, I have all inputs and outputs as undefined and no waveforms whatsoever. Any guidance would be appreciated!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity overall_attendance_data is
  Port (OUTPUTDATA_A    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_B    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_C    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_D    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_E    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_F    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_G    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_H    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_I    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_J    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_K    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OUTPUTDATA_L    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
        OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 downto 0));
end overall_attendance_data;

architecture Behavioral of overall_attendance_data is
    signal OVERALL_ATTENDANCE : unsigned(13 downto 0); 
begin
    -- '0' & prevents overflow
    OVERALL_ATTENDANCE <= ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_A)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_B)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_C)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_D)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_E)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_F)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_G)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_H)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_I)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_J)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_K)) + ('0' & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_L)); 
    
    OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT <= std_logic_vector(OVERALL_ATTENDANCE);
end Behavioral;
```

Testbench viewed below, testing all inputs equal to 1.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_tb is
end;

architecture bench of OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_tb is

  component overall_attendance_data
    Port (OUTPUTDATA_A    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_B    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_C    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_D    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_E    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_F    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_G    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_H    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_I    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_J    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_K    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OUTPUTDATA_L    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
          OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal OUTPUTDATA_A: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_B: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_C: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_D: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_E: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_F: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_G: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_H: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_I: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_J: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_K: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OUTPUTDATA_L: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
  signal OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 downto 0);

begin

  stimulus: process
  begin
    
       OUTPUTDATA_A <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_B <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_C <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_D <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_E <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_F <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_G <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_H <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_I <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_J <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_K <= "000000001"; OUTPUTDATA_L <= "000000001"; wait for 100ns;
  end process;

  dut: overall_attendance_data port map ( OUTPUTDATA_A                => OUTPUTDATA_A,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_B                => OUTPUTDATA_B,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_C                => OUTPUTDATA_C,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_D                => OUTPUTDATA_D,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_E                => OUTPUTDATA_E,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_F                => OUTPUTDATA_F,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_G                => OUTPUTDATA_G,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_H                => OUTPUTDATA_H,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_I                => OUTPUTDATA_I,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_J                => OUTPUTDATA_J,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_K                => OUTPUTDATA_K,
                                          OUTPUTDATA_L                => OUTPUTDATA_L,
                                          OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT => OVERALL_ATTENDANCE_DATA_OUT );

end;
```

[Simulation results from testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7ohS.jpg)

Comment: The OVERALL_ATTENDANCE assignment statement in overall_attendance_data should have produced a simulation error and refused to proceed during initialization. That error is part of a [mcve]. The expression on the right hand side (length 10) doesn't have a corresponding element for the target (length 14). Also note the missing separator between the numeric literal and the identifier in the physical literal (100ns). This is non portable. The standard requires at least one separator (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.3  Lexical elements, separators, and delimiters).

Comment: `OVERALL_ATTENDANCE <= ("00000" & unsigned(OUTPUTDATA_A)) +` ... and the `('0' & ` on the remaining operands are not required. Operands are evaluated from left to right and the result of the remaining additions will be the length of the first addition. That'd allow removal of the outer set of parentheses for those remaining operands as well.